# Photoshop Elements trial taking too much harddrive space

Tags: windows-7, installation, adobe-photoshop

I just installed Photoshop Elements 9 trial on Windows 7 64 Bit, and while it claims to use about 2GB of harddrive space, 4GB are gone after installing it (after removing the downloaded installation files, and cleaning windows temp folder and all system restore points).

Are there any files/folders that are save to be removed? Maybe also files in a hidden temporary installation folder?

Running a small SSD with 3 OSes, so I'm low on disk space.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to check the size of the scratch disk.  The settings are under Edit -> Preferences -> Performance.  The scratch disk is basically a private swap file that Photoshop uses when performing memory and computationally intensive operations (among various other things).  You can change the size of the scratch disk to suit your needs.  Do note, though, that a small scratch disk will reduce the performance of operations in Photoshop that are computation intensive.  This is generally not that big of a deal for minor photo editing and touch-up.

Comment: The setting I have lets me choose how much RAM is used, so I tried it, but it does not have an effect on disc usage. Also, I can change the partition for working volumes, but this did not have an effect either.